# Macro/UDF to extract multiple occurances of text URLs from cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have about 1000 rows of data and each cell in column C is filled with the html of a blog post article. I need to extract any URL (text string) that starts with "https://" and end with ".jpg"

there are multiple occurrences of each of these URLs in each cell, and some cells have other URLs in them too (none are hyperlinked, it's all plain text)

I've tried a bunch of FIND, IF, MID etc... but it only works for one occurrence.

can anyone help with a macro? thanks!

Comment: *can anyone help with a macro* - Way outside the scope of SO! Read [ask] and [mcve]. You'll also benefit from using `RegExp`, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following formula in D1 (or any other column that suits you):

```
=IF(AND(LEFT(C1,8)="https://", RIGHT(C1,4)=".jpg"),C1,"")
```

And copy down.

Comment: I have other URLs that don't need changed so it has to be http://blog, I assume that would just change the number 8 to 12. Also pretty sure this is only going to show me once occurence.

Comment: If you have different requirements, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52540496/edit) accordingly. Yes, the formula will only give you the results for one row, that's why I said to copy it down.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just doing it in a much simpler way with a basic find and replace. at first I thought each URL would be too different, but the only differences were 2 folders, (paths) at the end of each url like: 2017/01/filename.jpg. So I just did a find and replace on the root url before that to the new url path, and then did a find and replace on each month folder, to remove it. it only went back to 2010 or so.

for the record just to unnecessarily defend myself the original question says "there are multiple occurrences of each of these in each cell which is why I was fairly certain I needed a macro but obviously there was a much simpler way, per usual!